# rails: preventing bad/conflicting database migrations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, ruby-on-rails-5

Just wondering if these can be prevented via rubocop or directly via ci somehow.

We initially had a few migrations on our master branch:

```
# migration 1
create_table :some_table do |t|
  t.string :some_col
end

# migration 2
def change
  rename_column :some_table, :some_col, :some_other_col
end
```

However we also had a separate/older branch where the column in `some_table` was renamed directly:

```
create_table :some_table do |t|
  t.string :some_col
end
```

which got merged in/passed ci & ran on production without any issues, however got caught when it threw a `No such column: some_table` error when being deployed on a fresh test environment several weeks later.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from : [rake db:schema:load vs rake db:migrate](https://www.axiomq.com/blog/rake-db-migrate-vs-rake-db-schema-load/) that explains this exact issue:

> when you are adding a new migration to an existing app then you need
>   to run rake `db:migrate`, but when you join to existing application
>   (especially some old application), or when you drop your applications
>   database and you need to create it again, always run rake
>   `db:schema:load` to load schema.

Essentially when you are spinning up a fresh instance, always load the initial database with `db:schema:load` from then on you can migrate as usual.

Comment: ah, thanks!
would still be interested to know if these can be caught before a merge (to possibly prevent issues on older environments where migrations are not up to date)